# Flickering when viewing WebXR content

Tags: virtual-reality, polyfills, webvr, webxr

In android Chrome 80, when the **WebXR device API** flag is disabled, I expect the Webxr polyfill should play the VR output. But the content is flickering and I am not able to hit any object in VR world. Any idea why this is happening?

If the **WebXR device API** flag is enabled, I am getting the output correctly. I included the webxr polyfill (https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-polyfill) , but not sure whether it is working or not. How to check whether polyfill is giving the correct output? Do we need to build the **WebXR Polyfill** separately to support chrome 80?

Comment: WebVR was removed completely in chrome (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/webvr-1-1-removed), so the polyfill doesn't have any API to fallback to. are you getting the WebVR API when disabling XR?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am creating the output using WebXR. But if the WebXR device API flag is disabled, I am expecting it to fallback to polyfill API. Since I am using the polyfill, I can see it shows the enter XR button and I am able to enter and see the content. But it is flickering and I am not able to hit any objects. As mentioned in the webxr-polyfill github page, we have to specify the browser targets in .babelrc file. What does that mean? Do I need to add the chrome version in it and build the polyfill js file myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting the **preserverDrawingBuffer** flag to true while creating the renderer https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.preserveDrawingBuffer